# dirichlet problem for laplace's equation

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle, harmonic-functions

How can we show that a Dirichlet problem for Laplace's equation in a finite region has a unique solution.

Usually we can consider u2 - u1, a difference in values.

Comment: Can you use the maximum principle?

Answer (score 2):

If $u_1$ and $u_2$ solve Laplace's equation on the same domain with the same boundary conditions, then $u_2 - u_1$ solves Laplace's equation with $0$ boundary conditions.  The maximum principle now implies that $u_2 - u_1 = 0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not so sure if we can use the MaxPrinciple. Can you illustrate with another attempt? Thanks